# How to workaround truncation of text description for elements in qgis-modeler 2.18.15?

Tags: qgis, export, qgis-modeler, png

I am trying to make a QGIS processing workflow through the Graphical Modeler (QGIS 2.18.15). I have completed it, and wish to export it as a *.PNG. However, the elements and algorithms I added to the modeller are visually incomplete (unable to see the whole text written per element).

*At present, it looks like this*[image: Processing modeller]

*Since I wish to export it, I want it to visually look like the following example sourced online.*
[image: Graphical modeller e.g.]

**How do I customize it such that my text per element is not truncated?
And, is it possible to customize the aesthetics of the QGIS graphical modeller (within our outside of QGIS)?**

Comment: As far as I know, resizing the boxes in the modeller is not possible. You could you an external flowchart building program, or abbreviate your descriptions.

Comment: Can you edit the question title? Exporting as a PNG is not your problem, there's a button for that, a better title would be "How to stop truncation of descriptions in qgis-modeler"

Comment: I've just written a short python function that can export the modeler scene as an SVG file, which you can then load into Inkscape (or any other SVG) editor and tweak the appearance however - change fonts, put gradients on the boxes... Needs integrating into the modeler plugin though...

Comment: And just heard that QGIS3 has "Export to SVG" in the modeler anyway!