# Converting QGIS Processing Modeler Python (.py) file to (.svg)

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

A Processing Modeler can be saved in QGIS 2.18.15 as a Python (.py) file. Adhering to good advice by [@Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) in an [earlier thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268730/how-to-workaround-truncation-of-text-description-for-elements-in-qgis-modeler-2), I wish to know what are the many ways the (.py) files for the QGIS Processing Modeler can be converted into other formats such as the Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg) which can be used in a SVG-editor e.g. Inkscape as suggested by [@Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) (or for other file formats) where I can create an aesthetically neat graphical representation of the QGIS Processing Modeler, unlike in the QGIS Processing Modeler user interface where it can be challenging to align the elements in the modeller, since there is no Grid (like in [yED graph editor](https://www.yworks.com/yed)).